# golang get the reflect.Type of a type

Tags: reflection, go

Is it possible and how to get the reflect.Type of a type without creating an object from the type and calling on it `reflect.TypeOf(obj)`

What in java will be: `MyType.class`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can achieve this without an instantiation with the following syntax;

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

type Test struct {
}


func main() {
    fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf((*Test)(nil)).Elem())
}
```

play; https://play.golang.org/p/SkmBNt5Js6

Also, it's demonstrated in the reflect example here; https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#example_TypeOf

Comment: And if you're trying to get the `Type` for `Test` rather than `*Test`, you call `.Elem()` on the `Type` returned by `TypeOf`.

Answer (score 4):

No you can't have it directly, because in Go structs have no accessible fields to get their type.

One may think of tweaking it by doing the following:

```
type object struct {}

func main() {
    var obj object
    t := reflect.TypeOf(object)
    fmt.Println(t)
    // main.object
}
```

However, in Go every variable is initialized with its **zero value**, so this is perfectly equivalent to:

```
t := reflect.TypeOf(object{})
// main.object
```

If you look at Golang's source code, you'll see that `reflect.Type` is an interface implemented differently according to types, however you do not have access to those informations.

But, what you can do is get the type of a pointer to the struct and from there, get the actual type. The process is the same, except that a pointer's zero value is `nil`, so it takes less time to instantiate:

```
func main() {
    ptr_t := reflect.TypeOf((*object)(nil))
    fmt.Println(ptr_t)
    // *main.object

    t := ptr_t.Elem()
    fmt.Println(t)
    // main.object
}
```

Comment: Good answer, but the first code block has a typo, should be "t := reflect.TypeOf(obj)"